# Expose Docker container to public ip

Tags: networking, ssh, docker, lxc

I started an Ubuntu Docker container, installed ssh, run ssh with port 22 attached to it.

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND             PORTS             
f580e36aa7f0   martin/ssh2    /usr/sbin/sshd -D   0.0.0.0:49154->22/tcp
```

From my server I can now ssh my container. It work fine!

```
ssh root@172.17.42.1 -p 49154
```

**But how can I ssh my container from the outside word?**  
(my server is running in my local network on 192.168.1.8/24)

- Should I install a load balancer who redirect 192.168.1.8:2222 to 172.17.42.1:49154?
- Should I need pipework for that? How?
- Can someone point me in the right decision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to connect to your container at **192.168.1.8:49154** already.

Your ssh container is bind to 0.0.0.0 (=any interfaces) and port 49154 so it means container port 22 is accessible on any interface on your host at port 49154.